# Automatic payment with Paypal for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have a list of users and their credit card(Visa & Master) credentials.I would like to make the payments programmatically via code and not the general flow of going to paypal interface.I'm using woocommerce plugin and woocommerce  hooks.

How can I do this with Paypal plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here.  Are you saying you have a list of customer credit card numbers that you want to save in WooCommerce so the users can submit future orders with the saved card data?  Or are you just wanting to offer people the ability to save their payment method so they can checkout more quickly in the future?  Please clarify what your goal is and I can help.

Comment: Its a complete backend process.

I have a set of files generated programmatically .These files will have the credit card credentials of the user.I want to make the payment on a button click.The button can be clicked anytime and on clicking the button the payment should be made.This payment is not done on a fixed interval.Anytime I click the payment should be made.

Answer (score 0):

What you're explaining would require in-depth and expensive procedures for PCI compliance since you are saving sensitive card details in files on your server.  It's highly recommended you don't do that.

That said, however you're gathering the card data, you can use PayPal Pro to process the payment directly via the API.  Have you looked into that yet?

What would be best for you would be to setup an Authorization for people when you collect their card details.  Then instead of saving the card details in your file you just save the transaction ID from the Authorization.  Then you can process the actual payments using reference transactions where it would pull the card details saved at PayPal's server to process the payment instead of saving anything sensitive on your own server.